# Ajax Results Div Hidden Until Result

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an Ajax form which is working properly:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 alert alert-info" id="result"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <h4>Contact Us</h4>
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
                {
                    @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Email)
                    @Html.EditorFor(a => a.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Email)

                    @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Name)
                    @Html.EditorFor(a => a.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Name)

                    @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Phone)
                    @Html.EditorFor(a => a.Phone)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Phone)

                    @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Message)
                    @Html.EditorFor(a => a.Message)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Message)
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message" />
                }

            </div>
```

However, the results div, which I'd like to be styled as an alert, is always displaying by default. How can I make it display only when it has inner text? Is there something like `@if(AjaxResult != null) { <div>...</div> }`?

I suspect this can be solved within the View only, but I'm including my Controller code below for completeness:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ContactUsViewModel model)
        {
            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("X", "X");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("X", "X");
            string fromPassword = "X";
            string subject = "GN Query";
            string body = model.Message;

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }

            return Content("Your message has been received and we will respond within 24-48 hours.", "text/html");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a partial view call `_alert` with your html:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 alert alert-info" id="result">
Your message has been received and we will respond within 24-48 hours.
</div>
```

and then in your view you can set a container div in which it will be rendered when ajax call completes:

```
<div id="messageContainer">
</div>
```

now your action should return that partial view and you can have a boolean in your view to decide either render or not:

```
 @model System.Boolean
 @if(Model)
 {
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 alert alert-info" id="result">
       Your message has been received and we will respond within 24-48 hours.
   </div>
 }
```

your controller action will decide either the operation was successful and show the message or not:

```
bool isSuccess = true; // your logic to set this flag
............
............
{
     smtp.Send(message);
}

return PartialView("_alert.cshtml",isSuccess );
```

and in main view you will have :

```
 <div id="messageContainer">
 </div>
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "messageContainer" }))
```

Hope it helps.